# Turning a recursion into an iteration in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, iteration, hashtable

I get a *stack overflow error* due to my recursion creating an infinite loop. Turning the method into an iteration would stop this, but I have no idea how!

Can anyone guide me in turning my recursion into a loop?

```
private int findEmpty(int startPos, int stepNum, String key) {
    if (arr[startPos] == null) {
        return startPos;
    }
    return findEmpty(getNextLocation(startPos, ++stepNum, key), stepNum, key);
}
```

It is specifically `return findEmpty(getNextLocation(startPos, ++stepNum, key), stepNum, key);` that causes the error!

Comment: If your recursive code recurses infinitely, so will an iterative version of it.

Comment: I suspect the problem is actually with `getNextLocation`, so we can't diagnose the problem without seeing that code. I suspect the following is not your problem, but it also looks like you're using `++stepNum` in a way you don't expect; the way you have it, `stepNum` is the same at every iteration and is `stepNum+1` inside of `getNextLocation`.

Comment: You asked an almost-identical question yesterday. It isn't even closed. Why did you abandon that question and ask this one?

Comment: edits must not invalidate existing answers. ask new, followup question with link to this one if needed! specifically, your [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65066122/3) is a great candidate; it would attract specific answers no doubt. the newer revisions ask about completely different code, so merit yet another separate post. :)

Comment: I see, thanks! @WillNess

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive call is in tail position. Thus it already describes a loop. Just need to make it explicit, syntactically:

```
private int findEmpty(int startPos, int stepNum, String key) {
  while( True ) 
  {
    if (arr[startPos] == null) {
        return startPos;
    }
    // return findEmpty(getNextLocation(startPos, ++stepNum, key), stepNum, key);
    ++stepNum;
    int nextPos = getNextLocation(startPos, stepNum, key);
    // return findEmpty(nextPos, stepNum, key);
    startPos = nextPos;
  }
}
```

I don't code in Java. If the above code is non-compliant in any way, please regard it as a pseudocode and change into something suitable.

Comment: It's okay, though it is non-idiomatic to mutate the arguments of a function. However, this could easily circumvented by moving the values into auxiliary variables before the loop starts and then mutating those.